# Why does `gather` behave this way, and what can we do about it?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm having trouble with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\underline{First set of identities.}\end{center}
\[x+x = x\]

\begin{center}\underline{Second set.}\end{center} \begin{gather*}
    0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
    (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Basically, the `gather*` command is creating more space than the usual `[\ \]`. Why is `gather*` doing this, and what can we do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `center` environment not playing well with `gather*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \underline{First set of identities.}
    \[x+x = x\]
\end{center}%
\begin{center}
    \underline{Second set.}
    \begin{gather*}
        0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
        (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
    \end{gather*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, since there seem to be a duplication of skips, you can do an `\unskip` after the problematic `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \underline{First set of identities.}
\end{center}%
    \[x+x = x\]
\begin{center}
    \underline{Second set.}
\end{center}\unskip
    \begin{gather*}
        0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
        (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll present two possible solutions.

1. Don't close the `center` environment
2. “Abuse” the `gather*` environment

At the top is the rendering with your input. Note that I removed underlining, which is frowned upon by typographers. Instead of `\textbf` you can also use `\textit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\underline{First set of identities.}\end{center}
\[x+x = x\]

\begin{center}\underline{Second set.}\end{center} \begin{gather*}
    0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
    (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
\end{gather*}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{center}\textbf{First set of identities.}
\[x+x = x\]
\textbf{Second set.}
\begin{gather*}
    0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
    (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
\end{gather*}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{gather*}
\textbf{First set of identities.}\\
x+x = x \\[2ex]
\textbf{Second set.}\\
0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can load the `nccmath` package. I tried, thinking of using its `\useshortskip` command and discovered that just loading it works. Note that it loads amsmath, so that you can load it *instead of*  amsmath. It doesn't load `mathtools` (recommended extension of amsmath), though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\underline{First set of identities.}\end{center}
\[x+x = x\]

\begin{center}\underline{Second set.}\end{center} %
\begin{gather*}
    0+x = x, \quad x+0 = 0 \\
    (x+y)+z = x+(y+z)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. So it seems that the amsmath gather command has a bug.

Comment: It's not the first one since `mathtools`, by default, fixes two bugs of amsmath. Note that `nccmath` also has problems under certain circumstances that I don't remember at the moment (never met those problems myself).